# I can't find product types UI

Tags: commerce

I'm trying to add a new product type, but I can't find the tab for the product types.

In [Manage product structure](https://docs.drupalcommerce.org/commerce2/user-guide/products/manage-product-structure), it is very clear where that tab is, but I cannot find it.

I'm using Drupal 7.59 and Commerce Kickstart 2 with demo.

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.drupalcommerce.org/commerce2/user-guide/products/manage-product-structure contains documentation for Commerce 2.x, which is based on Drupal 8.

You're using Drupal 7, which is Commerce 1.x, so you need to find and follow the Drupal 7 documentation. That should be as simple as clicking "Commerce 1.x" in the left-hand navigation panel.

Comment: thank you for your answer :) , you are right, the problem remains the same, i can't find the product-type tab, when i go to  <mydomain>/admin/commerce/products/types i get 404.

Comment: Presumably you don't have the Commerce Product UI module installed?

Comment: i have Product ui installed but i still don't have the UI

Comment: Any help? i tried to install a fresh installation of kikstart and the problem is same!!!